# Cannot cast DBNull to a object using the james montemagno's geolocation plugin

Tags: ios, xamarin, geolocation

I'm currenly using the james montemagno's geolocator plugin to get longitude and latitude, and work in a view, in another it gives me an error

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Even though i don' receive any sort of error in my first view.

My code is this:

```
Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                            var idk = locator.IsGeolocationAvailable;
                            var idk2 = locator.IsGeolocationEnabled;

 Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position= await locator.GetPositionAsync();
```

The error happear when i do:

```
 await location.GetPositionAsync()
```

I tried to use the xamarin essential geolocator plugin, but gives the same exact error in the same place.

Comment: Have you checked if locator == null?

Comment: Have you add permissions in your project and check if your project has permission?You can refer to the sample https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/tree/master/samples/GeolocatorSample/GeolocatorSample

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro yes, locator is different than null. @ LucasZhang yes, if fact in my main i can process my location correctly, Thx for the questions